# Передача видеопотока с камеры одного iphone на другой

Tags: ios

Здравствуйте уважаемые эксперты!

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли примеры реализации приложений, таких как "камера" на apple watch, где на часах транслируется изображение с камеры iphone? Есть ли примеры стиримминга видеопотока с камеры одного телефона на другой? Хочется изучить технологию реализации такой задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Да, есть пример - стандартное приложение фотоаппарата. Оно транслирует текущий видоискатель напрямую на часы и позволяет сделать фото с их помощью.